# How do I view the source of Markdown files on Github?

Tags: github, markdown

Github helpfully renders Markdown (`.md`) files to HTML when viewing on github.com (for example, [this `README.md`](https://github.com/github/hub/blob/master/README.md)).

When viewing any other source file, it is shown as unrendered source code (for example, [this `.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/hub/blob/master/.gitignore)). A handy feature this gives is linking directly to a line in the source by clicking the line number (for example, [like this](https://github.com/github/hub/blob/master/.gitignore#L5)).

**How can I view the unrendered source of Markdown files on Github** (so I can link to a particular line in the source)?

***note***: I know of the "Raw" button, however it does not provide any of the nice UI Github has.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you don't want to use the "raw" button, you can ([since June 2021](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-06-30-parameter-to-disable-markdown-rendering/)) add `?plain=1` to your GitHub markdown file URL:

> Appending `?plain=1` to the url for any Markdown file will now display the file without rendering.
>
> As with other code files, it will also show line numbers, and can be used to link other users to a specific line or lines.
> For example, appending `?plain=1#L52` will highlight line 52 of a plain text Markdown file.

Example:

https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/README.md?plain=1#L49-L51

---

[Since Sept. 2021](https://twitter.com/github/status/1443572280924147717), there is a button which adds the `?plain=1` for you:

[image: plain]

Answer (score 7):

Use the "Raw" button. For instance, if you were looking at [README.md](https://github.com/github/hub/blob/master/README.md) there is a Raw button in the Navigation. This can be simple URL change (from blob to raw), but in this case becomes [a separate link.](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/hub/master/README.md)

Edit: There is no "pretty" view for the Markdown source. There's the converted HTML view, the Raw view without the UI, and the Blame view. Only the Blame view provides you with the ability to link to a specific line within the source.

Edit 2: The other option is to use Anchors within the README.md. If you take [the Installation title](https://github.com/github/hub/blob/master/README.md#installation) for example, you can directly link within the content of the Markdown file. Assuming you don't have anything hidden within the Markdown itself, this is closer still to solving your original question.

Comment: See my comment from the question: `note: I know of the "Raw" button, however it does not provide any of the nice UI Github has.` One of the things I'm after is `linking directly to a line in the source by clicking the line number`, which the "Raw" button doesn't give.

Comment: That's the closest you'll get under your requirements though. You can either have the raw view to see the code, or the blame indentation to get to the line - https://github.com/github/hub/blame/master/README.md#L5

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer - glad to see there are at least some workarounds :)

Answer (score 5):

Using the "Blame" button, you are able to see the source of the Markdown (for example, [like this](https://github.com/github/hub/blame/master/README.md#L70)).

Unfortunately, "Blame" comes with extra UI elements which make the source more cluttered.

Comment: You can link to a range of lines using the syntax https://github.com/github/hub/blame/master/README.md#L70-L72 You can select the range in the GUI by clicking the first line number, then Shift-click the second line number. To convert the URL from having a branch name, e.g. `master` to having a stable commit hash, press `y`.

Answer (score 1):

[Refined Github](https://github.com/sindresorhus/refined-github) provides an additional "Raw" button to view the raw source and link to a specific line:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue, as a complete surprise to me, on a file with a `.wiki` extension. It appears that files with `.wiki`, `.mediawiki`, and `.wikitext` extensions are recognized and rendered as HTML, with a table of contents even. I guess it makes sense, what with GitHub projects having wikis and all.

That's nifty, but this one particular case, I really *wanted* the raw wikitext to be visible and copy-pasteable, not some rendered representation of it.

The only half-way solution I found was to use a bogus file extension that isn't [one of the ones recognized by GitHub](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml), and then a `.gitattributes` to tell GitHub how to syntax highlight it, *e.g.*:

```
*.wiki_ linguist-language=mediawiki
```

I'm not thrilled about this, but all the good extensions were already "taken" according to the `languages.yml` linked above.