# How do I view the source of Markdown files on wiki Github?

Tags: github, markdown, wiki, plaintext

How do I view the raw source of a wiki `github` file, like [this](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Here-Cheatsheet):  (without closing the wiki repo)

NOTE: I don't see a raw button for a wiki `github` page (which was the proposed solution for
[How do I view the source of Markdown files on Github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985359/how-do-i-view-the-source-of-markdown-files-on-github) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attach `.md` to the URL.

https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Here-Cheatsheet.md

will redirect to

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/adam-p/markdown-here/Markdown-Here-Cheatsheet.md

Answer (score 2):

therobinkim's method doesn't work for me .

If you don't mind download all the wiki, just change clone command from

```
git clone https://github.com/[user]/[repo].git
```

to

```
git clone https://github.com/[user]/[repo].wiki.git
```